# export paper model in multiple pages

Tags: python

Link below gives a pepakura 3d model unwrap Python script by Adam Dominec (Thank you to him).

Is there a way to export or have it in multiple page format, so printing becomes easy?

[paper model](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model)

[image: island]

Comment: I just tried it and it does export in multiple pages by default if you choose `.pdf` export. In `svg` it splits it by file (`name_page1.svg`, `name_page2.svg`) and so on as AFAIK **svg** doesn't support multiple pages natively.

Comment: Get it. See image above. Is it possible to reduce number of faces from 32 to 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7. So this will come on different pages.  Currently in pds too it gives 3 islands on two pages. I need more islands than 3 ( atleast 8-9 ).